# Flutter how can i check api response is error or not

Tags: flutter, dart

I am simply using an api for login. Its working fine I need to just print if its showing an error in response

My code

```
  _trySubmit() async {
    final isValid = _formKey.currentState.validate();
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();

    if (isValid) {
      _formKey.currentState.save();

      print(_userName.trim());
      print(_userPassword.trim());

      var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();

      map['username'] = _userName.trim();
      map['password'] = _userPassword.trim();
      
      Map<String,String> headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json'};
      final msg = jsonEncode({"username":_userName.trim(),"password":_userPassword.trim()});

      http.Response res = await http.post(
        'http://api.igiinsurance.com.pk:8888/insurance_Igitakaful/mobile/login.php',
        headers: headers,
        body: msg,
      );
      var data = json.decode(res.body.toString());
      print(data);
      print(data['Cnic']);
      if(data['Cnic'].length > 2) {
        final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();
        await storage.write(key: 'Cnic', value: data['Cnic']);

        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
        );
      }
      else{
        print('error');

      }

    }
```

You can see I am using if else condition like when data['Cnic'] have length greater then 2 it will change the page but I need to check if its showing error in response its just print you have error or something

Comment: You can use `statusCode` to check if the returned response is an HTTP error so you can handle it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the statusCode property to determine error in the response.

```
if ( res.statusCode >= 400 ) {
        // handle your error here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( res.reasonPhrase  ==  'OK' ) {
       // all ok
}else {
    // something went wrong with the server!
}
```

---